# Cloudformation event to trigger Lambda using Cloudwatch

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to trigger Lambda in Cloudwatch event. The event should only when Cloudformation stack is COMPLETE, not earlier.
In Cloudwatch I need to write an event pattern.

```
  {
    "source": [
      "aws.cloudformation"
    ]
  }
```

Could someone tell me how to do it or direct to some examples?
Lets say my CF stack name is "RDS" and Lambda funcion RDS-upload.

Thanks !!!